# R won't predict a continuous variable using a bayesian network (Throws Error)

Tags: r

I'm running into an error using bnlearn in R to try and predict a continuous variable:

```
library(bnlearn)                       # Load the package in R
data(gaussian.test)
training.set = gaussian.test[1:4000, ] # This is training set to learn the parameters
test.set = gaussian.test[4001:4010, ]  # This is test set to give as evidence
res = hc(training.set)                 # learn BN structure on training set data 
fitted = bn.fit(res, training.set)     # learning of parameters
pred = predict(fitted$C, test.set)     # predicts the value of node C given test set
```

The error I get reads:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "bn.fit.gnode"
```

I could not find anything googling the error. I got the example from [another thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96271/prediction-of-continuous-variable-using-bnlearn-package-in-r), where it seems to have worked.

What am I missing?
I'm grateful for every hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default, most Bayesian network algorithms assume that all the variables are binary (yes/no) consisting of ones and zeroes, and not continuous.  Thus, probably check the data requirements/options for the R-package you're using.  [Bayesian networks which use continuous variables](http://www.sc.ehu.es/ccwbayes/members/aritz/documentos/FlexibleClassifiers-Aritz-TechReport06.pdf) commonly employ kernel density estimation (KDE).  You could try searching for a Bayesian network package that uses the Epanechnikov kernel, which is one of the most common kernels used for KDE.

I looked at your R-code, and after tweaking some of the dependencies, you need to use the following code to make a prediction and obtain the accuracy:

```
    library(bnlearn)                       # Load the package in R
    install.packages("Rcpp") 
    install.packages("forecast", dependencies = TRUE) 
    library(forecast)
    data(gaussian.test)
    training.set = gaussian.test[1:4000, ] # This is training set to learn the parameters
    test.set = gaussian.test[4001:4010, ]  # This is test set to give as evidence
    res = hc(training.set)                 # learn BN structure on training set data 
    fitted = bn.fit(res, training.set)     # learning of parameters
    pred = predict(fitted, "C", test.set)  # predicts the value of node C given test set
    cbind(pred, test.set[, "C"])           # compare the actual and predicted
    accuracy(f = pred, x = test.set[, "C"])

            pred          
 [1,]  3.5749952  3.952410
 [2,]  0.7434548  1.443177
 [3,]  5.1731669  5.924198
 [4,] 10.0840800 10.296560
 [5,] 12.3966908 12.268170
 [6,]  9.1834888  9.725431
 [7,]  6.8067145  5.625797
 [8,]  9.9246630  9.597326
 [9,]  5.9426798  6.503896
[10,] 16.0056136 16.037176
> accuracy(f = pred, x = test.set[, "C"])
                ME      RMSE       MAE      MPE     MAPE
Test set 0.1538594 0.5804431 0.4812143 6.172352 11.26223
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The package (bnlearn) does support continuous variables. And in the thread that I linked the exact same example code worked. I just don't understand why it does not work for me. Could someone maybe try it on their R Installation? (I already updated R and all packages without success.)

Comment: Maybe use 'predict' instead of "predict".   If that doesn't work, it may be that nothing is handed to the prediction module after learning.  Have you tried to exactly replicate a worked example with the same commands and same data?  What happened?   If that doesn't work -- then it could be your R installation, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did (replicate a working example (link above)). And as far as I can tell the prediction-module does receive "an object of class "bn.fit.gnode"" which it does not know what to do with. What do you mean with "use 'predict' instead of "predict""?

Comment: Use an apostrophe ' instead of "

Comment: I did not user either. The error message just prints it as "predict" with two "

Comment: Did you see this question with answers?   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96271/prediction-of-continuous-variable-using-bnlearn-package-in-r

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That did it!